# Naming elements of a list as a function of x in r

Tags: r, list, indexing, naming

Here I am trying to name the individual elements of this list as a function of x so that I may index it later like one would with a dataframe or vector, yet I keep getting the error message

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "Indxlist <- sapply(1:1600, function(x) list( (x) ="
```

Here is the code that I am attempting to use...

```
Indxlist <- sapply(1:1600, function(x) list( (x) = dataframe1[,x]))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Using an example data, your code works.  Do you 1600 columns in your dataset?

Comment: my bad, the code had parentheses around the x. I am trying to name the elements $1 through $1600 so they don't change when I index specific ones.

Comment: the problem with that is that the element names with "x" are all "$x"

Comment: Is there a way to get the column names to be $1 through $1600 instead of [[1]] through [[1600]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this cannot work. You cannot name a list with integers. Just do this after your command (which is not good practice anyways):

```
names(Indxlist) <- 1:1600
```

Comment: That worked! And thanks for the good practice note. As can be seen, I'm very new and inexperienced with coding. Thank you for the help though!

Comment: Glad, if that helped. If you want to accept this answer, I'd appreciate it. :)